# ngIf check if a variable exists

Tags: angular

right now I am using ngIf to see if Item Id is 1 and it does some style changes, but the 2nd statement still runs for the all other objects that don't have item Id of 1. I understand why it is happening, but is there a way to only run the 2nd statement if Item Id of 1 doesn't exist in any of the objects in the array? Thanks a Bunch

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items">    
     <div *ngIf="(item.details.id == 1)">
        Do Somthing
     </div>

     <div *ngIf="(item.details.id != 1)">
        Do Somthing
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: also update your json

Answer (score 3):

In component code:

```typescript
// private oneExists: boolean = false;
this.oneExists = this.items.filter(item => item.details.id === 1).length > 0;
```

In template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">    
  <div *ngIf="item.details.id === 1">
    Do Something
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="! oneExists">
    Do Something
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So Items is inside another array, so it is more like `let item of product.items` I am having a bit of issue accessing items in the constructor with the filter, any suggestions what is the best way to access items for this purpose knowing product if also a child of products array.

Comment: You probably shouldn’t access them in the constructor. Where is that `this.product.items` initialized? I suppose in a promise called in `ngOnInit`. If so, move my filtering code there. If somewhere else, move that code _right after_ `this.product.items` initialization. And declare `private oneExists: boolean = false;` somewhere on the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing with strict operators as below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">    
     <div *ngIf="(item.details.id === 1)">
        Do Somthing
     </div>

     <div *ngIf="!(item.details.id === 1)">
        Do Somthing
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What OP means is that don't execute the second if, if  one of the elements inside `items` does not contain `details.id = 1`.